# PythonにおけるPerlのrequire文のようなものは?

Tags: python, perl

こんにちは. Perlを5年ほど学んでいましたが, この度Pythonを学び始めることにしました. 初学者です.
現在PythonでWebアプリケーションを作ろうと思っているのですが, Perlでは`require "foo.cgi"`のように記述することで同じディレクトリにあるfoo.cgiというライブラリを読み込むことができました. Pythonにも`import`以外にこのPerlの`require`のようなものは存在するのでしょうか?

追記: つまり, コンパイル時ではなくスクリプトの実行時に評価される読み込みの関数がPythonにはあるのかなと疑問に思いました.

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　「`import`以外に」とのことですが、ということは何か`import`では不可能な機能を持った構文をお探しなのでしょうか？　たとえば動的インポート機能をお探しなのかな、と思ったのですが……。

Comment: @nekketsuuu ご返信ありがとうございます. Perlにおけるrequire文のように, コンパイル時ではなくスクリプトの実行時に評価される読み込みの関数がPythonにはあるのかなと疑問に思いました. importがそれにあたるのでしょうか?

Answer (score 1):

perlで言う`use`に対する`require`のようなものが、pythonにあるかという意味でしょうか。
パッケージ名ではなくファイルパスからランタイムにインポートしたいという。

## python2

```
import imp
your_module = imp.load_source('your_module', './path/to/your_module.py')

your_module.your_function()
```

## python3

```
import importlib.util
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location('your_module', './path/to/your_module.py')
your_module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(your_module)

your_module.your_function()
```

質問文にあるcgiファイルをライブラリとしてrequireという場面はちょっと考えづらいです。
.cgiではなく.plファイルかなと思います。